# Invert colors with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

How do I invert the colors of an image using the ImageMagick `convert` tool, so that black becomes white and white becomes black?

In other words, I want to turn this:

[image: original]

into this:

[image: inverted]

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Use the `-negate` option:

```
convert input.png -channel RGB -negate output.png
```

The `-negate` option replaces each pixel with its complementary color. The `-channel RGB` option is necessary as of ImageMagick 7 to prevent the alpha channel (if present) from being negated. (Thanks to [goto-bus-stop](https://superuser.com/users/91390/goto-bus-stop) for this [insight](https://superuser.com/questions/1194468/invert-colors-with-imagemagick#comment2051657_1194469).)

See also the [documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#negate) for `-negate`.

Comment: this made my black and white png completely transparent...

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: The transparency problem is because the alpha channel is also inverted. Use `-channel RGB -negate` to avoid that.

Comment: That's interesting. The ImageMagick on my system (version 6.8.9) only negates the RGB channels, and not the alpha channel by default, so `-channel RGB` isn't necessary. It only inverts the alpha channel if I pass `-channel RGBA -negate`. I'm not sure what explains the different behavior.

Comment: It works for me, without negate. What I'm curious about though is: while `identify` sees the input as "8-bit sRGB", the output is "8-bit Grayscale Gray".

Answer (score 12):

ImageMagick 6.x can invert color intensities with -negate option only.
ref) https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#negate

```
convert input.png -negate output.png
```

ImageMagick 7.x requires the -channel option with -negate.
ref) https://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli Changed Options

```
convert input.png -channel RGB -negate output.png
```

This is because the default active channels contain transparency(opaque/alpha) in ImageMagick 7.x

```
ImageMagick6: DefaultChannels = ((AllChannels | SyncChannels) &~ OpacityChannel)
ImageMagick7: DefaultChannels = AllChannels
```

Most algorithms update the red, green, blue, black (for CMYK), and alpha channels.
Usability of -negate seems to be sacrificed for overall consistency.

More detail for you. http://blog.awm.jp/2018/11/18/im7negate/

Comment: `convert input.png -negate output.png` works fine for me on ImageMagick 7.0.8 (ArchLinux)

Comment: There is no problem on RGB image without transparency. RGBA with transparency image cause problem, only ImageMagick7.

Comment: You can check PNG file has transparency or not.
`identify -verbose input.png | grep Type`  It ouput TrueColor or TrueColorAlpha.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I went ahead and added `-channel RGB` to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For powershell (Windows OS) need use:

```
magick input.png -channel RGB -negate output.png
```

Note. I using it in imagemagick 7.1.1-18